# Разница между singleton в Java и в Spring

Tags: java, spring

Наткнулась на такие строки про область видимости Singleton в Spring:

> Note that there is a subtle difference between the instance obtained
>   using the Java Singleton pattern and Spring Singleton. Spring
>   Singleton is a singleton per context or container, whereas the Java
>   Singleton is per process and per class loader.

Мой перевод:

> Обратите внимание, что существует тонкая разница между экземпляром, полученным 
>   с использованием шаблона Java Singleton и Spring Singleton. Spring 
>   Singleton уникален в рамках контекста или контейнера, тогда как Java
>   Singleton - в рамках процесса или загрузчика классов.

И, во-первых, хотелось бы удостовериться, что мой перевод правильный. А во-вторых, хотелось бы глубже понять разницу между singleton в Java и в Spring...

Comment: Здесь имеется ввиду локальный синглтон, который существует не в рамках процесса, а в рамках некоторого scope. Почитать: https://j2eereference.com/difference-springs-singleton-singleton-design-pattern/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Перевод верный.

> Spring Singleton уникален в рамках контекста или контейнера

Это значит, что каждый раз, запрашивая singleton-бин из одного и того же контекста, вы будете получать один и тот же объект:

```
ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");
MySingleton s1 = ctx.getBean("mySingleton", MySingleton.class);
MySingleton s2 = ctx.getBean("mySingleton", MySingleton.class);
// s1 == s2
```

Но если синглтон будет получен из другого контекста или будет создан НЕ Spring'ом (через `new` или какой-нибудь другой контейнер), вы получите другой объект.

```
ApplicationContext ctx1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");
ApplicationContext ctx2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/application-context.xml");
MySingleton s1 = ctx1.getBean("mySingleton", MySingleton.class);
MySingleton s2 = ctx2.getBean("mySingleton", MySingleton.class);
MySingleton s3 = new MySingleton();
// s1 != s2
// s2 != s3
// s1 != s3
```

> Java Singleton уникален в рамках процесса или загрузчика классов

Это значит, что в рамках одного процесса JVM вы не сможете создать два разных экземпляра класса синглтона`*`. В этом случае сам класс-синглтон должен конроллировать процесс создания собственных экземпляров (в отличие от предыдущего случая, где этот процесс контроллируется контейнером Spring'а). Обычно этого добиваются, делая конструктор `private` и разрешая получать экземпляры класса только через статический метод этого класса, который всегда отдаёт один и тот же объект.

`*` Это можно попытаться обойти при помощи Reflections API, загрузки одного и того же класса несколькими classloader'ами (отсюда оговорка "в рамках загрузчика классов") или другими грязными хаками.

Comment: Да, спасибо, стало гораздо понятнее. Только не могу ещё понять, почему ctx1 и ctx2 - это разные контексты (ведь создаются они при помощи одного и того же конфигурационного файла)?

Comment: Конфигурационный файл - просто описание набора компонентов. Он не является уникальным идентификатором контекста. Создав контекст два (или более) раза из одного и того же описания, вы получите два (или более) разных контекста, содержащих одинаковый набор компонентов. Заметьте, не одни и те же, а одинаковые. Это значит, что увидев в конфигурационном файле бин класса `MySingleton`, Spring создаст новый объект, а не станет искать уже созданные объекты в других контекстах, загруженных из того же конфигурационного файла.